# What is the highest SAT score on record for someone with moderate intellectual disability?

Tags: intelligence

What is the highest SAT score on record for someone with moderate intellectual disability?

> The SAT standard deviation is 217 points, which means that most people
> scored within 217 points of the mean score

Has anyone with moderate ID ever scored 1600 or near to that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not information that is generally disclosed during testing. It is difficult to determine such a thing without proper testing. Research would mean either finding a pool of participants who met some defined standard of an “intellectual disability” and administering the test, or locating the results of tests taken by people vetted as such. I do not know how you would go about determining that, however.

I realize this doesn’t answer the question but I hope it helps understand why it has not been answered.

Comment: Worth noting: the SAT correlates highly with IQ tests which are the determiner of intellectual ability. The question is asking the equivalent of "What's the highest IQ score a person with a low IQ score has gotten?". Or more properly, what the correlation is between IQ score and SAT, I can't find a quantifiable measure (excepting an old army IQ test at 0.82 
 to 0.86), just the statement that it's "high".

Comment: I feel your interpretation is an oversimplification but if that is the intended meaning perhaps the wording should more clearly reflect that it is supposed to be that general.

Comment: It's a simplification, perhaps I overdid it. SATs aren't that familiar to me being in the UK, but what little I gleaned from a search is in my comment.  I'm not sure they're intended to *be* an IQ test per se, but the relationship is intimate apparently. As with everything, diligence in studying makes a big difference no doubt plus other factors.

Comment: The distinction to me I suppose is how generally to interpret “mental disability.” 

An SAT is mainly for college entry and taken during high school. It is notoriously biased but also something that can be prepped for. Theoretically one could have a learning disability and do well on the test. 

However, my point was just that we would generally not know their IQ for comparison to consider how high a low IQ person scored.